# Are there any IdentityServer4 services (not endpoints) for token handling?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 and a web API in the same project, and I would like to use  IdentityServer token handling in my own controllers, e.g. I want to issue tokens, refreshtokens, revoke tokens in my own controllers without calling other built in IdentityServer endpoints.
Are there services for stuff like this I'm missing?
Thanks

I need something like *someIdentityServerService* below

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginRequestDto model)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
        {
            return BadRequest("Wrong email or password!");
        }

        // do some other stuff

        var token = await someIdentityServerService.GetAccessTokenAsync(user);
        return Ok(token);
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: IdentityServer is just an API, it's a very specialized API, but an API nonetheless. As such you can interact with it via `HttpClient` as you would any other API. If you want a "service", just create a class to contain the `HttpClient` and  expose the calls you need to make as methods. Then you can use this class in your application.

Comment: @Chris Pratt I don't think that's true, there are services like IIdentityServerInteractionService  (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/interactionservice.html) which allow you to do some stuff on service level, e.g. revoke tokens and stuff, I need something similar, that can be used for full token management of an API (handling tokens and refreshtokens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think, it's a good idea to come inside the certified IdP and call the internals in your own order, not the order defined by the protocol.

Nevertheless you can do that by looking into [the implementation](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default) and invoking or overriding. Identity Server is highly flexible, using standard DI you can override almost everything.

for instance

```cs
            var identityPricipal = await _principalFactory.CreateAsync(user);
            var identityUser = new IdentityServerUser(user.Id.ToString())
            {
                AdditionalClaims = identityPricipal.Claims.ToArray(),
                DisplayName = user.UserName,
                AuthenticationTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                IdentityProvider = IdentityServerConstants.LocalIdentityProvider
            };
            var request = new TokenCreationRequest();
            request.Subject = identityUser.CreatePrincipal();
            request.IncludeAllIdentityClaims = true;
            request.ValidatedRequest = new ValidatedRequest();
            request.ValidatedRequest.Subject = request.Subject;
            request.ValidatedRequest.SetClient(Config.Clients().First());
            request.Resources = new Resources(Config.IdentityResources(), new List<ApiResource>());
            request.ValidatedRequest.Options = _options;
            request.ValidatedRequest.ClientClaims = identityUser.AdditionalClaims;
            var token = await _tokenService.CreateAccessTokenAsync(request);
            token.Issuer = "...";
            return await _tokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(token);
```

More convenient way of creating tokens is to employ [IdentityServerTools](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html). However that's aim is to help calling external APIs from within IdSrv, not issuing any JWTs by external requests.

If you need to request JWTs from outside (and follow the protocol), you have to use predefined endpoints and signatures.

Comment: I edited the original question, so basically I need services that implement token handling (get accesstoken and refreshtoken, refresh accestoken with refreshtoken, revoke refreshtoken), which I can use in my own controllers (without calling other endpoints). Hope it's more clear now

Comment: You **can** get access and refresh tokens with *Resource Owner Password* flow. You can't logout as there is no session at all in that case. There are more possibilities when you switch from JWT to reference token, but I do not think you intend to

Comment: I know there are endpoints for these things, but as I mentioned, I need services, that do the same thing, I don't want to call an other endpoint in my custom endpoint.

Comment: You mean *services* in terms of ASP.NET Core DI architecture? Hard to get it from your question. So you would like to be able to create any valid token from within IdSrv host application, right? If so, look into IdentityServerTools [http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/tools.html]

Comment: thanks, do you know anything similar for refresh token handling?

Comment: I've proposed some changes for future reference, please accept, than I will mark your answer accepted. Thanks

Comment: Updated and committed. Uncheck if you don't like, but my opinion's that the preamble is vitally necessary "for future reference". You wanted to manage refresh tokens. Follow the link an see the corresponding svc. That's it.